# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError when trying to upload an image

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using the following code to upload the image in /public/uploads/ folder in my root rails directory.

```
 uploaded_io = params[:product_image]
 File.open(Rails.root.join('public','uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
 end
```

My form looks like this

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :configure_product}, :multipart => true) do %>
<%= label_tag(:product_image, "Image:") %><br />
<%= file_field_tag 'product_image' %>
<%= submit_tag "Save and add another", :name => 'save and add another' %>
<%= submit_tag "Save", :name => 'save' %> 
<% end %>
```

but when trying to submit the form I get the following error.

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in ConfigureCategoryController#configure_product

"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I replaced the writing mode from 'w' to 'wb' and now I am getting

NoMethodError in ConfigureCategoryController#configure_product

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

New at rails. Would surely appreciate the help.

Comment: Well then how did you fix it?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to open the file as a binary file by appending b to the open type.

```
File.open("#{ Rails.root }/tmp/uploaded_image.gif", "wb") do |f|
```

The other issue you're having is specific to whatever it is your application does.